# How to convert svg to pdf in landscape mode using Inkscape?

Tags: pdf, svg, inkscape, pdf-conversion

I have used inkscape (https://inkscape.org/release/0.92.3/windows/64-bit/) to convert svg file to pdf. And I used the following command

```
"./inkscape.exe " + svgFilePath + " --export-area-drawing --export-pdf=" + pdfFilePath
```

and

```
"./inkscape.exe " + svgFilePath + " --export-area-page --export-pdf=" + pdfFilePath
```

The generated pdf is in portrait mode in both cases. I want to convert my svg to pdf in landscape mode. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first command you have given here should generate a pdf with actual visible area or the bounding box of visible objects(looks like landscape). I always use that command to convert my svgs to pdfs. The second command generates pdf similar to portrait mode

Comment: [‎10/‎31/‎2018 5:47 PM]  Anuja B. G.:  
Thank you. I have tried it again and I got the pdf as you said. But I want to generate the pdf (using --export-area-drawing) with a margin or padding. Is it possible?